# Getting 'UnicodeDecodeError' when trying to send mail with Python

Tags: python, datetime, email, smtp, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email using python but everytime I try to send, I'm getting `UnicodeDecodeError`. Where am I doing wrong? I couldn't figure out by searching on web.

Here's my full code:

```
import smtplib
import random
import datetime

# Random name list
names = ['Jack', 'Kevin', 'Laura']

# Datetime get time
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%a, %b %d')

# Random order id's
r0 = random.randint(702, 711)
r1 = random.randint(1111111, 9999999)
r2 = random.randint(1111111, 9999999)
r3 = round(random.uniform(13, 25), 4)

# Mail content
mailc = """Hi {}! You did it buddy: #{}
Service: Standard
*Profit: S$ {}
Send it no later than {}...
""".format(random.choice(names), {r0}-{r1}-{r2}, {r3}, date)

# Subject
sub = '(.LO) New toy: {}-{}-{}'.format({r0}, {r1}, {r2})

# Mail adreesses and password
senderAddress = 'xxx@gmail.com'
senderPass = 'xxyyww'
receiverAddress = 'yyy@gmail.com'

# Server
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(senderAddress, senderPass)

# Message
message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(sub, mailc)
server.sendmail(senderAddress, receiverAddress, message)
server.quit()

print("Mail sent.")
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WINDOWS 8.1\Desktop\automaticOrderEmailSender.py", line 35, in
<module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  File "C:\Users\WINDOWS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtpl
ib.py", line 261, in __init__
    fqdn = socket.getfqdn()
  File "C:\Users\WINDOWS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socke
t.py", line 676, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 1: invalid
continuation byte
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: Are you sure about this format? `format({r0}, {r1}, {r2})` You are creating sets. It is ok for the string placeholder, but probably not what do you want for `format` argument. In any case it seems a problem to connect to the server (the server name). Are you sure you are using the above example? Maybe delete the `"` and first and last char and retype them. Sometime (and some editor) add extra formating code with copy/paste sequence

Comment: Yes, you're right. I deleted the brackets from format funcs. But the problem is still appearing.

Comment: could you rewrite (with keyboard) the line `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)`. It seems that there is a wrong character in there, or try to find (using you OS) which IP you get. Maybe you just setup a fake server, with some error in the host name resolution